# Error while loading shared libraries: 'libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

I just installed Passenger 3.0.11 and [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) and got this error:

> Starting nginx: /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message means what it says.  The `nginx` executable was compiled to expect the PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expression) shared library to be available somewhere on LD_LIBRARY_PATH or specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or whatever equivalent library-locating mechanisms apply to your operating system, and it cannot find the library.

You will need to install PCRE - or configure your environment so that `nginx` will look for the PCRE library where it is installed.

Comment: I already install PCRE. Could you pleas tell me to configure environment to fix this.

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Where did you install PCRE?

Comment: any further on this? I'm still having the same problem

Comment: @redroot: In the short-term (to get it working) you can add the directory where PCRE is installed to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and try running again. If that works, then you need to investigate `/etc/ld.so.conf`. If it doesn't work, then you need to check whether Ruby is 32-bit and PCRE is 64-bit, or whether Ruby is 64-bit and PCRE is 32-bit. The mixture won't work. If you have a mixture, reinstall the correct version (bittiness) of one of the products, but PCRE alone is simpler than Ruby plus its extensions. Use `file` and `ldd` to analyze binaries and shared libraries.

Comment: As a guy who is working through nginx builds, I'm finding the configure system a bit unflexible. For example, configuring with OpenSSL assumes you want linking to a shared object. Its appears impossible to force static linking to `libssl` and `libcrypto` when both the static archive and shared object are present. Careful placement of `-Bstatic` and `-Bshared` does not help.

Answer (score 71):

I got the same error, and I fixed the problem by running `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: I had installed PCRE manually before passenger installation (trying to solve another error with that version of passenger) and got this error when tried to start nginx. "sudo ldconfig" helped me too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be the answer for at least Ubuntu 11

Comment: Thansk, helped me too for the same error, I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I was trying to generate a SWIG interface for python and got the same error. this solution worked.

Answer (score 10):

Execute below command and restart server again.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an old post, but hopefully might be useful for someone.
I was trying to install/start up an older version of **NGINX** on **Amazon-Linux 2** and encountered this error.
NGINX is expecting `libpcre.so.0`, but the library wasn't available on Amazon-Linux 2.

**Solution**

1. Searched for a later version of `libpcre.so` using `find / -name libpcre.so*`
2. I found `libpcre.so.1` symlinked to `libpcre.so.1.2.0` in `/usr/lib64/`
3. I created a new symlink to `libpcre.so.1.2.0` and named it libpcre.so.0 using `ln -s libpcre.so.1.2.0 libpcre.so.0`
4. Restarted NGINX and it worked

Comment: any downside for forcing to using another version of lib?

Comment: I haven't seen any issues with this in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are few recommendations, with this I have solved the issue which I had.

- As mentioned above add the lib path in the /etc/ld.so.conf and check the same is updated or not by using `ldconfig -v`
- Add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the `.bash_profile` and refresh the same with `. . bash profile`.
- If the lib file is not get updated then use the  `updatedb` to refresh the library list.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after I installed ClamAV, Antivirus for my Linux server.

```
[root@10 ~]# yum install clamav clamav-db clamd -y
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, kabi, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify,
              : versionlock
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package clamav.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjson-c.so.2()(64bit) for package: clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package clamav-db.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package clamd.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package json-c.x86_64 0:0.11-13.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch                         Version                              Repository                  Size
====================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 clamav                          x86_64                       0.100.3-1.el6                        base                       1.3 M
 clamav-db                       x86_64                       0.100.3-1.el6                        base                       150 M
 clamd                           x86_64                       0.100.3-1.el6                        base                       243 k
Installing for dependencies:
 json-c                          x86_64                       0.11-13.el6                          base                        27 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================
Install       4 Package(s)

Total download size: 152 M
Installed size: 154 M
Downloading Packages:
Setting up and reading Presto delta metadata
Processing delta metadata
Package(s) data still to download: 152 M
(1/4): clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                       | 1.3 MB     00:00
(2/4): clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                    | 150 MB     00:01
(3/4): clamd-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                        | 243 kB     00:00
(4/4): json-c-0.11-13.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                         |  27 kB     00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                               100 MB/s | 152 MB     00:01
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : json-c-0.11-13.el6.x86_64                                                                                        1/4
/sbin/ldconfig: libraries libpcre.so.0 and libpcre.so.1 in directory /lib64 have same soname but different type.
  Installing : clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64 [#############################                                                  ] 2/4
  Installing : clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                   2/4
  Installing : clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                      3/4
  Installing : clamd-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                       4/4
  Verifying  : clamd-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                       1/4
  Verifying  : clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                      2/4
  Verifying  : json-c-0.11-13.el6.x86_64                                                                                        3/4
  Verifying  : clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                   4/4

Installed:
  clamav.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6              clamav-db.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6              clamd.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6

Dependency Installed:
  json-c.x86_64 0:0.11-13.el6

Complete!
[root@10 ~]#
[root@10 ~]# grep: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
grep: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

[root@10 ~]# grep: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Later I found below libraries got deleted from /lib64

```
libjson-c.so.2.0.1
libjson.so.0.1.0
libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
```

I copied those from other server and uninstalled ClamAV.

```
Running Transaction
  Erasing    : clamd-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                       1/3
  Erasing    : clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                      2/3
warning: /etc/freshclam.conf saved as /etc/freshclam.conf.rpmsave
  Erasing    : clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                   3/3
  Verifying  : clamd-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                       1/3
  Verifying  : clamav-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                      2/3
  Verifying  : clamav-db-0.100.3-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                   3/3

Removed:
  clamav.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6              clamav-db.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6              clamd.x86_64 0:0.100.3-1.el6

Complete!
```

```
sending incremental file list
libjson-c.so.2.0.1
libjson.so.0.1.0
libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -1):

just reinstall h5py conda, solved for me