# PCRE issue when setting up WSGI application

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, uwsgi, pcre

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

I have been following a guide
[How To Set Up uWSGI and Nginx to Serve Python Apps on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04). Once I have set up the virtualenv I follow the instructions:

> `pip install uwsgi`
>
> You can verify that it is now available by typing:
>
> `uwsgi --version`
>
> If it returns a version number, the uWSGI server is available for use.

However when I do this I get:

> uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

If I push on and work further through the guide things fall over when I try use uwsgi.

My research tells me that PCRE is Perl Compatible Regular Expressions and several people have asked questions online with libpcre.so.1 issues with other applications.

For example a response to a [similar issue relating to nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501163/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpcre-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-f):

> The message means what it says. The nginx executable was compiled to
>   expect the PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expression) shared library to
>   be available somewhere on LD_LIBRARY_PATH or specified in
>   /etc/ld.so.conf or whatever equivalent library-locating mechanisms
>   apply to your operating system, and it cannot find the library.
>
> You will need to install PCRE - or configure your environment so that
>   nginx will look for the PCRE library where it is installed.

But I can't find much relevant to installing PCRE or configuring it. Most install instructions use: `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` and then reinstalling uwsgi `pip install uwsgi -I`. As in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669354/rebuild-uwsgi-with-pcre-support). Where I have tried everything posted and got nowhere.

I think my principle issue is that I don't understand the problem very well or how to do the things mentioned in the nginx example above.

Any insight or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's usually supplied by libpcre3 (pcre e.g. version 8.39) but not included in Debian/Ubuntu packages. Neither in old versions.

The easy way is to compile pcre3_8.39.orig.tar.bz2  http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libpcre3 
and copy `libpcre.so.1.2.7` to /usr/lib/, and make the links libpcre.so.1, libpcre.so .

Or make a "compat" package.deb libpcre1 with the files.

Comment: Please edit your above post to include OS name, version, architecture. Like Debian Jessie - amd64, Ubuntu 16.04 - i386  , etc.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I'm struggling with your exact problem right now.

Answer (score 9):

Even though my context may be different, the following steps should help you as well.

I did `pip install uwsgi` into my environment created by `conda create -yn <env_name> python`. Note, that one wouldn't even need to install PCRE into the environment, because it is included with `Anaconda`. We can see this issue in the environment, after `source activate <env_name>`:

```
# uwsgi --version
uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open...
```

With root/sudo access you can find where `libpcre.so.1` is/will be:

```
# find / -name libpcre.so.1
/opt/anaconda3/lib/libpcre.so.1
```

Now let Linux know how to access it:

```
# ldconfig /opt/anaconda3/lib/
```

That's all you need to make it work. You can see the change you are making:

```
# find / -name uwsgi
/opt/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/uwsgi

# ldd -d /opt/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/uwsgi
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d1ba000)
        ...
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff98dbc5000)
undefined symbol: pcre_free     (/opt/anaconda3/envs/cts/bin/uwsgi)
```

**PS** Turned out `ldconfig` above populates global cache `/etc/ld.so.cache`, which, in my case, clashed with system library (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3`). So I had to revert the change by running `ldconfig` without parameters and resort to runtime linking = starting `uwsgi` as

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib uwsgi --version
```

Comment: It worked. Does this mean I have to type LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib before uwsgi everytime i use uwsgi