# Error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm currently trying to install [this GitHub library](https://github.com/ismrmrd/siemens_to_ismrmrd) on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine and I followed all the installation steps stated on the Github page. 
However, when I try to call the function `siemens_to_ismrmrd` in the command line, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5.so.101: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libhdf5 is installed on my machine, though. Typing `locate libhdf5.so` in the command line gives

```
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so.101
/home/username/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.so.101.0.0
/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib/libhdf5.so
/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib/libhdf5.so.101
/home/username/anaconda3/pkgs/hdf5-1.10.1-h9caa474_1/lib/libhdf5.so.101.0.0
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501163/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpcre-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-f) here on SO, it was suggested to run `sudo ldconfig`. This also didn't help in my case, the same error still pops up.

The command `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is recommended to look at in other questions returns nothing.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You may adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as suggested in the [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32560246/3440745) to the referenced question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your suggestion. Is this a safe command? I heard that a wrong setting of 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' could damage the system.

Comment: This would prefer libraries, installed for your user, over system-wide ones. If your libraries are correct, everything will be OK. At most it can damage your user.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on Debian 10 ([source](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1461#issuecomment-563118689)):

```
sudo apt install pkg-config libhdf5-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt install python3-h5py` after reinstalling. Solved the error for me in linux-aarch64